# nginx: two domains -> two apps -> one server

Tags: nginx

This supposed to be very simple, but I am struggling to set it up the whole day. Here are my conf files:

```
# Expires map
  map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}


server {
    listen  80;
    server_name www.firstdomain.com firstdomain.com;
    root /path/to/project/;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    server_name www.firstdomain.com;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    proxy_read_timeout  90;
    expires $expires;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_read_timeout  90;
        proxy_pass http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8001;

    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias /path/to/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {                        
        alias /path/to/media/;
    }

    location  /robots.txt {
        alias  /path/to/robots.txt;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/firstdomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/firstdomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = 'firstdomain.com') {
        return 301 https://www.firstdomain.com$request_uri;
    }

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://www.firstdomain.com$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
}
```

And this is my second domain, stored in a seperate file in sites-available:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.second-domain.com second-domain.com;
    error_log my-domain-path/nginx.log;

    location /
    {
        proxy_pass http://www.second-domain.com:8002;
    }
}
```

Both apps are managed by supervisor and both start successfuly. However, when i navigate to www.second-domain.com I get the content of the firstdomain.com.

I am sure that the second-domain content works and runs, because I can see it if I navigate to the IP:PORT location, but it's not working with the domain name.

Why?

EDIT: as request the result of nginx -t

```
 nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Comment: Is it linked in sites-enabled?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Yes, it is.

Comment: Check the output of `nginx -T` then.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I did that as well it's ok.

Comment: Clear your browser cache, then. Or give us something more to work with.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I try the cache ... what more would you want to see?

Comment: Start by actually _posting_ the output of `nginx -T`. And do not obfuscate the domain names.

Comment: That is the output of `nginx -t`, not the output of `nginx -T`. Please try again.

Comment: Seems that clearing the browser cache solved the issue. Thank you for your time and attention @MichaelHampton